# Summary of divergent series summation methods and relations between them?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, divergent-series

There are a number of methods of assigning sums to series that do not necessarily converge, e.g. Cesàro summation, Abel summation, Ramanujan summation, etc.  (There is also the trivial method of only allowing convergent series in the first place.)

Is there anywhere one can find a good summary of the various methods, their properties (linearity, stability...), and the relations between them?  (That is to say, does method A extend method B?  Does method A ever disagree with method B?)

Obviously it's impossible for such a thing to be comprehensive, but something including at least the most common ones and their variations would be nice.

(Note: I'm assuming all series are of real numbers.)

Thank you!

Comment: You could try Hardy's [*Divergent Series*](http://www.amazon.com/Divergent-Series-AMS-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821826492), if you haven't looked there already. (I don't know any more modern references. I'd be glad to learn of some myself!) Hardy's book touches on all the summations you mentioned, and more. (Note: Ramanujan summation is buried in the chapter on Euler-Maclaurin sums.) I don't recall how exhaustively the relations between the summation methods are explored, but I believe you will find at least some discussion in the vein you're asking about at various places in the text. (Go Blue!)

Comment: Try googling the phrase [*summability theory*](http://www.google.com/search?q=summability%20theory). This should get you started on more modern references.